# Concatenate each row of a matrix with each element of another matrix R

Tags: r, matrix, concatenation

I want to concatenate each row of a matrix (say m1) with each element of another matrix (m2). Here follows an exmple:

```
m1 <- t(combn(4,2))
m2 <- matrix(NA,nrow(m1),2)
for(i in 1:nrow(m1)){
    m2[i,] <- seq(1,4,1)[-c(m1[i,])] 
   }
> m1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    1    4
[4,]    2    3
[5,]    2    4
[6,]    3    4

> m2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    2    4
[3,]    2    3
[4,]    1    4
[5,]    1    3
[6,]    1    2
```

The matrix that I want should be like this:

```
> m3
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    2    3
 [2,]    1    2    4
 [3,]    1    3    2
 [4,]    1    3    4
 [5,]    1    4    2
 [6,]    1    4    3
 [7,]    2    3    1
 [8,]    2    3    4
 [9,]    2    4    1
[10,]    2    4    3
[11,]    3    4    1
[12,]    3    4    2
```

What is the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the expected output, the logic seems to be that we are expanding the rows of the first dataset by also includng the second dataset, so the number of rows should be double as of the first.  In the current approach, we used `rep` to expand the rows and then `cbind` with the `vector` created from the second `matrix`

```
cbind(m1[rep(1:nrow(m1), each = 2),], c(t(m2)))
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    1    2    4
# [3,]    1    3    2
# [4,]    1    3    4
# [5,]    1    4    2
# [6,]    1    4    3
# [7,]    2    3    1
# [8,]    2    3    4
# [9,]    2    4    1
#[10,]    2    4    3
#[11,]    3    4    1
#[12,]    3    4    2
```

Comment: This perfectly works even if the two matrices haven't the same number of columns, the each option will accommodate the latter issue. Thanks.